# iOS: access to firstviewcontroller by AppDelegate

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I want to access to an IBOutlet of my first Viewcontroller by AppDelegate class. My project is based with a **storyboard** and there isn't the reference with the first Viewcontroller.
What's the to do it?
I know that I should set this IBOutlet as a property in first Viewcontroller, but in AppDelegate? How I can access to it?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Maybe your app architecture/design is not good.

Comment: do you set this viewController as the rootViewController of your app's window somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your `rootViewController` from your app's delegate with :

```
self.window.rootViewController
```

Example :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    MyVCClass *firstVC = (MyVCClass*)self.window.rootViewController;
    [firstVC someMethod];

}
```

Careful, your ViewController may not have been yet loaded / initiated.

Comment: So, what's the way to call my FirstViewController?

Comment: @nazz_areno I added an example

Comment: @rdurand, the rootViewCotnroller might be nil in storyboards

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't set the rootViewController for your app's UIWindow, then doing 
 `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow rootViewController]` will give you nil.

If you use storyboards for your navigation then simply you can do this to get the rootViewController

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

First import your ViewController in AppDelegate.m like this :

```
#import "YourViewController"
```

Then in AppDelegate.m place the below code

```
 @implementation AppDelegate

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {

   YourViewController * view = [[YourViewController alloc]init];
    self.window.rootViewController = view;
 }
```